# WildFly Infinispan put get not working propertly

Tags: java, ejb, wildfly, wildfly-10, infinispan

**WildFly** 10.0.0-final

**Infinispan** 8.1.0-Final

Im working with 2 nodes same config standalone-full-ha

```
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=infinispan_cache:add( aliases=["infinispan_cache-alias"], default-cache=default_cache, start=LAZY)
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=infinispan_cache/transport=TRANSPORT/:add(lock-timeout=60000, stack=tcp)
/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=infinispan_cache/replicated-cache=default_cache:add(mode=ASYNC)
```

I get the cache in this way

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/infinispan/cache/infinispan_cache/default_cache")
private org.infinispan.Cache<String, Object> cache;
```

I'm using putForExternalRead then the other node knows the value using get,  the other side, everything go well, but when I use get from the node witch put the value, returns null.

```
cache.putForExternalRead("hola","Hola prueba");
Object o = cache.get("hola");//This o is null
```

Comment: putForExternalRead has very specific semantics. Does the same happen with a normal put call?

Comment: Yes, my workaround was wrap the object into another object with timestamps and save in 2 cache, a Map and infinispan, then when I get the object, I compare timestamp and return the newest

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this problem with the latest WF12 release?

Comment: Thats why I mention the versions, because in WildFly 10.1.0-final is working, but I can't change my Production Server Version.

Comment: Ah, so it is working in a later release...

Comment: Unless you're willing to upgrade your production server, I'm afraid you're out of luck.  We only have 1 branch for 10.x and even that branch has been inactive for 2 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to configure properly Jgroups with TCP stack and my own Cache under batch SYNC transaction

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
        ...
        <cache-container name="my_infinispan_cache" aliases="my_infinispan_cache-alias" default-cache="default_cache">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
            <replicated-cache name="default_cache" mode="SYNC">
                <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED"/>
                <transaction locking="OPTIMISTIC" mode="BATCH"/>
                <eviction strategy="NONE" max-entries="-1"/>
                <expiration lifespan="-1" max-idle="-1"/>
            </replicated-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
    ...
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:4.0">
        <channels default="ee">
            <channel name="ee" stack="tcp"/>
        </channels>
        <stacks>           
            <stack name="udp">
                ...
            </stack>
            <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                <protocol type="MPING" socket-binding="jgroups-mping"/>
                <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
                <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
            </stack>
        </stacks>
    </subsystem>
```